# language can not change in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud, required-field

I am using codeigniter with Grocery CRUD, I create a form with GC but the text in the required fields are in english and i want it in spanish. I read diferent documentation and I tray it but does not work.
This is my controller

```
$this->crud->set_table('test'); 
$this->crud->set_language('spanish');    
$this->crud->set_subject('Test');
$this->crud->columns('id_test','test'); 
$this->crud->required_fields('test');

$output = $this->crud->render();
$data['contents'] = 'contents';
$data = array_merge($data, (array) $output); 
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

and in the view show like this
[The text in the required field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBY54.png)

 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month I solve the problem. I add a folder **Spanish** in `system/language/` and inside a **form_validation_lang.php**. Although I change in `application/conf/conf.php` the default language for **Spanish**